# How to handle 'Widget Loading...' Message in Google Cloud's JupyterLab AI Platform?

Tags: python, ipywidgets, fairlearn

I am working on getting to know FairLearn in Google Cloud's AI Platform (via JupyterLab). For now, I am starting with the [tutorial](https://fairlearn.github.io/quickstart.html) and when I run the code for the Fairlearn Dashboard, I get an indefinite 'Loading widget...' as seen below.

[image: Image with Loading Widget]

I have been reading on other threads of users struggling with Wit-widget in JupyterLab to no avail.

Within my terminal in JupyterLab (within my conda environment), I did the following installations successfully:

```
> pip install ipywidgets

> jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension

> conda install -c conda-forge nodejs

> jupyter nbextension install --py --user witwidget

> jupyter nbextension enable witwidget --user --py
```

And within my jupyter notebook, I also include:

```
!jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager
```

I also have the following jupyterlab extension list:

[image: Image of Jupyterlab Extension List]

Answer (score 0):

JupyterLab is not yet supported, see https://github.com/fairlearn/fairlearn/issues/484#issuecomment-651095161 for reference.

You should be able to run this in Jupyter (not Jupyter Lab) directly, though.

Comment: Yes, I slowly came to that same conclusion. It doesn't seem to be working on the Google Cloud Platform at all, so working on it locally.